# Why was my Stop Limit Sell Executed?

Tags: stop-order

For BNB, I set it to trigger @ 260 and sell for 250.
It was sold today @ 11:56 EST.
I don't see that the price ever dropped below 260, so why did it execute the sell?
What am I missing?!? This is the first time I've used a stop limit order.
Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Even though you don't see a price below 260 using your data source, your data source may not include every market transaction, including the one that stopped you out.